# Using $slice on Meteor

Tags: mongodb, sorting, meteor, limit, slice

I'm having trouble using the `$slice` function in Meteor.
I've tried lots of combinations, including:

```
MyData.findOne( {}, { fields: { myArrayField:{ $slice:-1 } } } );
```

This just throws me an `illegal token exception`.

My plan is to use this along with sort, fields, and limit.

EDIT: This seems to work server side. I'm wondering if there's a similar solution client-side?